# Clickable textures

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, textures

I'm kind of new to LibGdx and android studio.
I'm trying to create clickable textures, one for play and one for credits.
Both should be opening a new empty screen/event.

```
public void create() {

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("Main_Screen.png");
    music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("bgmusic.wav"));
    music.play();
    music.setLooping(true);
    credits = new Texture("credits.png");
    play = new Texture("play.png");
}


@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.draw(play, 340, 1400);
    batch.draw(credits, 340, 400);
    batch.end();
}
```

However i'm unsure on how to do this since i'm also creating the background with a texture, so i'd be very happy if someone could assist me with helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Sprite` instead of `Texture`, that holds the geometry, color, and texture information for drawing 2D sprites.

MyGdxGame

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game {

    public Screen menuScreen,creditsScreen,playScreen;

    @Override
    public void create () {

        menuScreen=new MenuScreen(this);
        creditsScreen=new CreditsScreen();
        playScreen=new PlayScreen();

        setScreen(menuScreen);
    }
}
```

MenuScreen

```
public class MenuScreen extends InputAdapter implements Screen  {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture background,play,credits;

    Sprite backgoundSprite,playSprite,creditsSprite;
    private ExtendViewport extendViewport;

    OrthographicCamera cam;
    private float w=480;
    private float h=800;
    private Vector3 vector3;

    MyGdxGame game;
    Music music;

    public MenuScreen(MyGdxGame game){
        this.game=game;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        extendViewport=new ExtendViewport(w,h,cam);

        vector3=new Vector3();

        background = new Texture("Main_Screen.png");
        play=new Texture("play.png");
        credits=new Texture("credits.png");

        backgoundSprite=new Sprite(background);
        backgoundSprite.setSize(w,h);       // If resources are not in context of your viewport
        backgoundSprite.setPosition(0,0);  //Default Position

        playSprite=new Sprite(play);
        playSprite.setSize(100,100);
        playSprite.setPosition(w/2-playSprite.getWidth()/2,h/2+100);

        creditsSprite=new Sprite(credits);
        creditsSprite.setSize(100,100);
        creditsSprite.setPosition(w/2-creditsSprite.getWidth()/2,h/2-100);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

        music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("bgmusic.wav"));
        music.play();
        music.setLooping(true);   
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        batch.begin();
        backgoundSprite.draw(batch);
        playSprite.draw(batch);
        creditsSprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

        extendViewport.update(width,height);
        cam.position.x = w /2;
        cam.position.y = h/2;
        cam.update();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        vector3.set(screenX,screenY,0);
        Vector3 position=cam.unproject(vector3);
            if(playSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(position.x,position.y)) {
            game.setScreen(game.playScreen);
        }
        if(creditsSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(position.x,position.y)){
            game.setScreen(game.creditsScreen);
        }

        return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() { }

    @Override
    public void resume() { }

    @Override
    public void hide() { }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        background.dispose();
        play.dispose();
        credits.dispose();
    }
}
```

CreditsScreen

```
public class CreditsScreen implements Screen {

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) { }

    @Override
    public void pause() { }

    @Override
    public void resume() { }

    @Override
    public void hide() { }

    @Override
    public void dispose() { }
}
```

PlayScreen

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) { }

    @Override
    public void pause() { }

    @Override
    public void resume() { }

    @Override
    public void hide() { }

    @Override
    public void dispose() { }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpfull however the background has been resized and does not fit the screen anymore, how would i correct this?

Comment: size of `Main_Screen.png` is not in dimension of `480*800`(viewport size) because it cover whole screen so use all resources in the context of viewport world size.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to libGDX!

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to figure out how to change screens in your game. At a high level, this is what you'd need to do:

1. Draw your button texture on the screen.
2. Use `Gdx.input` to detect when the player lifts their mouse button (and if it's over one of your buttons when they do it)
3. Switch to the new screen (presumably with a new background) when this happens.

I would recommend that you first complete the ["A Simple Game"](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game) and ["Extending the Simple Game"](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game) tutorials in order to familiarize yourself with the basics of libGDX and the `Game` and `Screen` classes.

Next, try using Scene2D.UI (there are links at the bottom of the second tutorial) to add a [`Stage`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#stage-setup) and [`TextButton`s](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#textbutton) to your main menu.

Hopefully that helps you get started- there is a lot of helpful information on that libGDX wiki which I think you will find helpful.